# How to implement a Drupal Commerce multi-select membership donation form?

Tags: 7, commerce

Something like this using Drupal [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)? You select from a select list multiple options of which everyone has a price right? And so it adds it as a total below in a field like a cart, but in a same page and then below you fill your details and continue?
[image]

Or not a chance with Commerce and have to go with some other alternatives? Note I'm looking for Drupal friendly solution, not a PHP programmer here.

Cheers everyone for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are asking about the form specifically, but it isn't clear to me how you are actually managing your 'memberships'. Something like [CiviCRM](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/introduction-to-memberships/) that has full membership management tools can be integrated with both Drupal and with Commerce. There is a module for the latter, but we have found it problematic and have instead done the Commerce to CiviCRM integration using Drupal Rules and the [CiviCRM Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) modules.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try/experiment with the [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> provides a donation line item type along with a donation product and product display.
>
> In addition to being able to create a donation product, this module also provides a donation checkout pane, allowing customers to add a donation to their order as part of the checkout process.

**Note**: refer to [this tutorial/screencast](http://commerceguys.com/blog/using-custom-line-items-provide-donation-feature-drupal-commerce) also for a great introduction to this module.

Comment: When possible, please try to adapt your answers for the individual questions instead of posting the same answer to multiple questions.  If you can't tailor the answer for the question, then you are likely answering duplicate questions, so please flag as dups or vote to close as dups.  Thanks.